# What calls tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c

All the cells in my table are blank. I noticed that tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called, which I think is causing this to happen. What calls this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tableview calls its datasource methods.
In order for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to be called, there needs to **be** rows in the tableview, which the method `numberOfRowsInSection` is for.

Hop on over to the Apple documentation on the [`UITableViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDatasource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.